# How to install the latest Dirac codec on windows

Tags: windows, codec

How do I install the Dirac codec on windows?
Can I get this as part of the GStreamer project?

Comment: Hopefully I don't have to compile from source

Comment: When you break it down to its core, this really is a question about how to install software, which isn't really an Audio/Visual Production question.  It might fit better on SuperUser.  Might be borderline though, so I'm not sure what others will think.

Comment: I've managed to find a copy of libschroedinger-1.0-0.dll in GStreamer